# Take a 3-SAT system and compute its symmetry group, what can we say? How does this group relate to satisfiability?

Tags: group-theory, logic, computer-science, np-complete, satisfiability

Take for example, the $3$-CNF system:

$$
a \vee b \vee c = 1 \\
d\vee -e \vee f = 1
$$

The symmetry group of the first equation is $S_3 = \langle (x,y) : x, y \in \{a,b,c\}, x\neq y \rangle$ because obviously permuting that single equation's variables doesn't change the equation (up to ordering of the $\vee$-sum).

Now the second one is trickier because it has a $-e$.  Clearly, unless we incorperate some other type of symmetry, we can't permute into/out of the $e$.  Thus it's symmetry group is $S_2$.

**Question 1.** How do I express the symmetry group of the whole system in terms of $S_2, S_3$, is it external direct sum?

**Question 2.** Are there any properties of the groups involved that say something about satisfiability?  If you can't see any, how do you recommend I investigate this question further?

Comment: I believe it's just isomorphic to $S_2 \times S_3$ because we can permute those two systems independently.

Comment: Are you interested in intensional or extensional symmetries? I.e. consider the following system: $ a\lor a\lor a=1$, $\lnot a\lor b \lor b=1$, $\lnot b\lor \lnot b\lor \lnot b=1$. For you, is its symmetry group trivial or $S_2$?

Comment: My point is that syntactically, $a$ and $b$ appear to play different roles. But the truth table is invariant under swapping $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman the first has symmetry group $1$ in my definition, but if I wanted it to be non-trivial, I would do $a_1 \vee a_2 \vee a_3$ where it's understood that $a_i = a_j$ when evaluated.

Comment: @AlexKruckman what truth table?  Yes, I'm not sure exactly what is best for now, but let's just assume you don't permute into/out of the same letter.

Comment: @AlexKruckman the symmetry is preserving the equations up to $\vee$-sum rearrangement and re-ordering of the equations.   So if $\sigma = (a,b)$ does that, then yes.  So nothing like equisatisfiability, as we want these things to be easy to check.

Comment: In my example, swapping $a$ and $b$ does not preserve the equations up to reordering disjuncts and equations. But for any assignment of $a$ and $b$ to true and false, this assignment satisfies the system if and only if the assignment obtained by swapping $a$ amd $b$ does (since in my example, no assignment satisfies the equation). This is what I mean when I say that swapping $a$ and $b$ is an extensional symmetry. And my hunch is that this notion of symmetry is more meaningful than yours.

Comment: @AlexKruckman could you explain that more in an answer or provide smallish reference to peruse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that there are two reasonable notions of "symmetry group" here. I would call them "intensional" and "extensional". Let me make this precise.

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ propositional variables. I will define a SAT problem over $P$ to be a set of subsets of $P\times 2$. The elements of a SAT problem $S$ are called *clauses*. A SAT problem $S$ is a 3-SAT problem if each clause in $S$ has size $3$ (but everything I say here applies just as well to $k$-SAT problems for any $k$, or to general SAT problems).

For example, with $P = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, your system \begin{align*}
a\lor b\lor c &= 1\\
d\lor -e\lor f &= 1
\end{align*}
is written in conjunctive normal form (CNF) as $(a\lor b\lor c)\land (d\lor -e\lor f)$. Translating it to a SAT problem according to my definition, we represent it as: $\{\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)\},\{(d,1),(e,0),(f,1)\}\}$.

An assignment of truth values to $P$ is a function $f\colon P\to 2$ (viewing $1$ as representing "true" and $0$ as representing "false"). We say that an assignment $f\colon P\to 2$ *satisfies* the SAT problem $S$ if for every clause $C\in S$, there is some $p\in P$ such that $(p,f(p))\in C$.

So every SAT problem $S$ determines a Boolean function $ev_S\colon 2^P\to 2$, by $ev(f) = 1$ if $f$ satisfies $S$, and $ev(f) = 0$ otherwise. But different SAT problems can determine the same Boolean function.

Ok, now on to symmetry groups.

*Intensional version:* Let's agree to write $P$ as $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Then the group $S_n$ acts on $P$ in an obvious way, with $\sigma(p_i) = p_{\sigma(i)}$. This action extends to an action on $P\times 2$, by $\sigma(p,t)) = (\sigma(p),t)$. And thus to an action on $\mathcal{P}(P\times 2)$ (the set of clauses) by $\sigma(C) = \{\sigma((p,t))\mid (p,t)\in C\}$. And thus to an action on $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(P\times 2))$ (the set of SAT problems) by $\sigma(S) = \{\sigma(C)\mid C\in S\}$.

The *intensional symmetry group* of a SAT problem $S$ is $$I_S = \{\sigma\in S_n\mid \sigma(S) = S\}.$$

For example, the intensional symmetry group of $\{\{(a,1),(b,1),(c,1)\},\{(d,1),(e,0),(f,1)\}\}$ consists of those permutations of $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ which permute $\{a,b,c\}$, permute $\{d,f\}$, and leave $e$ fixed. This group is isomorphic to $S_3\times S_2$.

*Extensional version:* $S_n$ also acts on the set of all truth assignments $2^P$ by $f\mapsto f\circ \sigma$. The *extensional symmetry group* of a SAT problem $S$ is $$E_S = \{\sigma\in S_n\mid \text{for all $f\in 2^P$, $f\circ \sigma$  satisfies $S$ iff $f$ satisfies $S$}\}.$$ In other words, $$E_S = \{\sigma\in S_n\mid ev_S(-) = ev_S(-\circ \sigma)\}.$$
This is really the symmetry group of the Boolean function determined by $S$, rather than of the syntactic presentation of $S$.

Some observations and comments:

- $I_S$ is always a subgroup of $E_S$. This is an exercise in unpacking the definitions.
- If $S$ is not satisfiable, then $E_S = S_n$ (since $ev_S$ is the constant function with value $0$). The converse is not true.
- I doubt that there is any relationship betweeen $I_S$ and satisfiability, though I don't have anything precise to say along these lines.
- I don't know if $I_S$ has been studied before, but $E_S$ certainly has. See the notion of [symmetric Boolean function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_Boolean_function) - these are the Boolean functions such that CNF systems representing them have $E_S = S_n$. Googling for "symmetry group of a Boolean function" also turns up a few papers, such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11806).

Comment: Thank you! I read everything and understand it.  So extensional is probably what we want as it includes more symmetries typically.  So we can say that if our group $E_S \neq S_n$ then $S$ is satisfiable?  (Contrapositive of second bullet above).   I guess this suggests that computing $E_S$ is NP-complete?

Comment: Yes, you have the correct contrapositive. This does suggest (but doesn't prove definitively, since $E_S\neq S_n$ doesn't characterize satisfiability) that computing $E_S$ is difficult. Note that NP-complete problems are always Yes/No, so you'd want to look at questions like "does $E_S = S_n$?" or "is $E_s$ trivial"?

Comment: But computing $I_S$ is going to be easier, just check all swaps of variables $(a,b)$ and you've found the generators of $I_S$.  Represent $I_S$ as its list of generators.  Checking if two formulas are syntactically the same is going to be much easier I guess than determining the same thing but using $E_S$.